# Как в битриксе по id файла определить к какому инфоблоку он принадлежит?

Tags: файлы, битрикс

Допустимо решение через прямое обращение к таблицам БД.

Нужно для того, чтобы закрыть доступ без авторизации к файлам отдельных инфоблоков. Или есть какое-то лучше решение?

Comment: определить можно, но ресурсозатратно. Какова конечная цель, запретить открывать некоторые файлы по прямой ссылке?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov нужно запретить открывать по прямой ссылке файлы из некоторых инфоблоков, если пользователь не авторизован.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov насколько ресурсозатратно?

Comment: Попробуйте поступить по другому. Не публикуйте прямые ссылки из `upload`. Вместо этого сделайте чпу, например `downloads/{element_id}/{file_id}`. Тогда при скачивании вы уже заранее будете знать элемент (а соответственно и его инфоблок) и ид файла. Если по переходу по этой ссылке все права соблюдены, то отдавать контент файла, если нет, редирект на страницу ошибки

Comment: @DmitryKozlov как проверять, что file_id связан с element_id?

Comment: получить элемент, посмотреть файл, связанный с элементом, проверить, совпадает ли его ид с file_id

Answer (score 0):

Значения пользовательских полей инфоблоков находятся в таблице `b_iblock_element_property`, если сделать запрос типа `SELECT * FROM b_iblock_element_property WHERE IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID=12 AND VALUE=95`, то можно проверить, хранится ли файл с ID=95 в доп. свойстве с ID=12 (свойство принадлежит конкретному инфоблоку). Доп. свойства определяются в таблице `b_iblock_property`.

Comment: Как быть, если есть инфоблоки 2.0, в которых значения свойств хранятся в отдельной таблице?

Comment: Поищите по названию (коду) этой таблицы в базе - /bitrix/admin/perfmon_tables.php

Comment: не легче `CIBlockElement::GetList` использовать?

Comment: Легче, правильнее, но ниже скорость отработки. Если не критично - лучше использовать PHP API, главное понять принцип )